# Hardware/workflow for HD multicam shooting on a budget

Tags: video, camera, timecode, shooting

I'm interested in doing some multicam shooting of my band's gigs.  (This is a personal, not commercial, motivation, so my constraints include budget and cargo space — i.e., minimal equipment bulk.  And I need to make shot decisions after the fact since I won't have someone who can switch between shots live.)

So far I've shot simultaneously with two or three consumer/prosumer HD camcorders, each recording to its own MiniDV tape or disk, then bringing all the content into FCP and manually syncing.

**This works pretty well, except that the timecode is inconsistent** — if I sync all the clips at the beginning of the show, an hour later they'll all be a second or two out of sync.  So far I've dealt with this by retiming the clips — after syncing at the beginning, I go to the end and adjust the playback rate for some of the clips by a very small amount (e.g., change one clip to speed 100.01%, another to 99.97%) until they're closely in sync.  This is tedious.

**I'm wondering if there's a better way.**  I've seen cameras in the 5,000 – 10,000 USD range which have external timecode inputs.  But that's above my price range, and would require a timecode generator and an extra cable running to each camera (which I think would violate my "minimal equipment bulk" constraint).

Are there less-expensive cameras and/or techniques that would work better for this purpose?  What should I be looking for?

Answer (score 2):

More and more cameras are including GPS time sync now that they almost all use them for location information.  I am sure you can find a camera at any price range that includes this capability.  The GPS should keep your cameras within a few hundred milliseconds of each other.

Take them for a run at Best Buy or a similar store, letting them run for a while to see which keep in sync and which only sync on start-up.

The least expensive option is to put an AC quartz clock with a continuously sweeping hand on stage and occasionally have people "sync" by bringing it into view. :-)

I just looked on B&H for a reasonable camera and found this tip at http://www.bhphotovideo.com/find/newsLetter/Time-Code.jsp

> Experienced videographers will "stripe" the video tape with time code
>   prior to their shoots. To prepare the blank tape to be striped, they
>   rewind the blank tape to its very beginning, and with the lens cap on
>   the camera, press Record and record black from the very beginning to
>   the very end of the tape. Striping the tape burns time code to the
>   tape, and this time code will not change when recording your future
>   video footage to that tape. This can alleviate possible time code
>   inconsistencies that can be created by many types of camcorders.

This may be worth a shot with your current gear.

Comment: Thanks.  Good idea regarding GPS time sync — I'll investigate that.  (However I don't think timecode striping would help with syncing between multiple cameras.  It's typically used, I think, if you're going to be recording a bunch of clips on a tape nonsequentially.  Timecode striping is analogous to formatting a floppy disk before writing data on it — it just sets up the structure so the deck can find unique locations on the tape.)